# Can I move a kitchen waste vent? If so what is allowed?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, kitchen-sink

I an adding a large opening between my kitchen and living room just above countertop level, but realized the sink vent is there.

I want to move it ~30" away. See photos. My plan would be to use two street 1/16 elbows to get the 2" ABS into the wall, then run it through the wall vertically.

Is this allowed? Anything I'm missing?

[image: Diagram]

[image: Photo]

Comment: It is not clear to me that it would be a good idea to move the location of where the vent connects to the 2" horizontal drain to a location downstream of the sink. (The vent MIGHT need to be at or UPSTREAM of the sink.) Maybe it would be better to cut off the existing vent 2 ft or 2.5 ft above the floor and go laterally in the wall to outside the opening and then go vertically. (And instead of making a new penetration in the large beam, go back to the original vent routing through the beam? The top of the opening would be a little lower to accommodate the upper horizontal run of vent.)

Comment: Does anything above the sink drain into that stack?

Answer (score 2):

If that vent is only venting the lav, you can use an AAV [image: Air Admittance Valve]

Its approved by IPC, and many jurisdictions these days.